# I want to set a font color according to the value received from the API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I want to change my font color dynamically.

```
<div *ngIf="clientProfileModel.patientHealthScore[0].kidneyScoreStatusByColor==='Normal'" [ngStyle]="{color:'#ff5454'}" then *ngIf="clientProfileModel.patientHealthScore[0].kidneyScoreStatusByColor==='High'" [ngStyle]="{color:'#53D8A2'}" else *ngIf="clientProfileModel.patientHealthScore[0].kidneyScoreStatusByColor==='Normal'" [ngStyle]="{color:'#fd9b4b'}" > {{(clientProfileModel.patientHealthScores[0]!=undefined &&
                  clientProfileModel.patientHealthScores[0].kidney||'')+''}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one thing store your font color in the API response by modifying it.

for example (TS) :

and let's say you're fetching details from API

You just have to create one **function** which returns *color* based on your parameter like **-**

```
 this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.users = res;
      this.users.map((res) => {
        res.customColorForKedney = this.setColor(res.kidneyScoreStatusByColor); // call the function and passed your parameter whatever you have
        res.customColorForHeart = this.setColor(res.kidneyScoreStatusByColor);
        res.customColorForLiverscore = this.setColor( res.kidneyScoreStatusByColor);
        res.customColorForPancreas = this.setColor(res.kidneyScoreStatusByColor);
      });
      return this.users;
    });
  }
```

**Function to set color**

```
setColor(key) {
    let customColor;
    switch (key) {
      case 'Very High': {
        customColor = '#ff5454';
        break;
      }
      case 'High': {
        customColor = '#fd9b4b';
        break;
      }
      default: {
        // default case is for normal BP
        customColor = '#53D8A2';
        break;
      }
    }
    return customColor;
  }
```

*In HTML file* **:**

**[ngStyle]="{'color':customColor }"**

**Stackblitz demo**: It will surely help you. [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhmcxz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: i did this code but why the condition always reads else condition,the answer is equals High it should print first condition,      
  if(this.clientProfileModel.patientHealthScores[0]!=undefined && this.clientProfileModel.patientHealthScores[0].kidneyScoreStatusByColor === 'High'{
      this.customColor ='#ff5454';
    }else {
      this.customColor ='#53D8A2';
    }

Comment: I have added stackblitz demo.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're trying to display can you please explain a bit more so I can help you, I have added stackblitz demo to see if it can help, or else will find some other solution.

Comment: i have 7 inputs  example kidney,heart,liverscore,pancreas etc and i have three color code green for normal, yellow for low and red for high according to the value receive(low,normal,high) ill set the color, In the above stackblitz demo you have given answer for one input i want to make it for 7 or more inputs. Lets say when i get the data from the url ill get 7 or more inputs example kidney,heart,liverscore,pancreas etc and i want set all of this a color according to low normal and high values.

Comment: I have updated stackblitz demo please check

Comment: thanks for the help. i got one issue that says .map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use ternary operator instead of *ngIf. Because in angular you can't use multiple *ngIf in single tag.

`<div [style.color]="condition1 ? 'red' : (condition2 ? 'yellow' : 'green')">`

`<div [style.color]="clientProfileModel.patientHealthScore[0].kidneyScoreStatusByColor==='High'? '#53D8A2' : (clientProfileModel.patientHealthScore[0].kidneyScoreStatusByColor==='Normal' ? '#ff5454' : '#fd9b4b')">`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a good idea to push your logic to the component instead of keeping it in the template.

You can calculate the font color based on your business logic in the component:

```
fontColor: '#000000'; // A default value

// When your component initializes, decide what the font color should be
ngOnInit() {
    if (model.status === 'Normal') {
        this.fontColor = '#ff5454';
    } else if (model.status === 'High') {
        this.fontColor = '#53d8a2';
    } // and so on
}
```

And you can then use `fontColor` in your template:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{color: fontColor}">
    {{ ... }}
</div>
```